# Binary string search on one field

Tags: mysql

I have 300 boolean fields in one table, and I'm trying to do something like this:

One string field:

```
10000010000100100100100100010001
```

Here's a simple way to do a simple search of this field like:

```
select * from table where field  xor "10000010000100100100000000010001"
```

I'm trying this but is to long:

```
select * from test where mid(info,2,1) and mid(info,3,1)
```

:) Help!!

Comment: can't understand wat u wanna convey! Ha a simple way to do a simple search os this field like:

Comment: I have a solution for you, I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A citation from the book [High Performance MySQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101716):

> If you used an integer, you could write that example as follows:
>
> ```
> mysql> SET @CAN_READ   := 1 << 0,
>     -> @CAN_WRITE  := 1 << 1,
>     -> @CAN_DELETE := 1 << 2;
> mysql> CREATE TABLE acl (
>     -> perms TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
>     -> );
> mysql> INSERT INTO acl(perms) VALUES(@CAN_READ + @CAN_DELETE);
> mysql> SELECT perms FROM acl WHERE perms & @CAN_READ;
> +-------+
> | perms |
> +-------+
> |   5   |
> +-------+
> ```

**UPD**:

A possible solution in your case if all the strings are of the same length (I'll be surprised if they are not):

```
select * from teste where info like '_______00001001001001001___1___1';
```

Comment: @JYelton: no, I just wanted to say that packing in general might be a good idea, but packing as a string of 0 and 1 is hardly a good idea. Though it ocurred to me that thre is one more solution!

Comment: Using LIKE in that way is a quite clever solution. I think he will end up in a lot of trouble on maintenance side though, if he suddenly needs to change the structure of the string, or add/remove values from the string etc.. It's a maintenance nightmare, and his string is 300 long..

Answer (score 0):

Applying bitmasking to other types than ints, like strings in your case, is possible if you write your own external function and do the comparison in there, but this is somewhat hardcore stuff if you are not familiar programming with C. MySQL itself only provides bitmask operators for the int type it uses internally.

Edit: Or use the 'LIKE' solution provided by newtower

See other similar topics: [Is there a practical limit to the size of bit masks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177054/is-there-a-practical-limit-to-the-size-of-bit-masks)

While efficient in space and possibly speed, this approach to solve the problem has same disadvantages as having a table with 300 columns. A table with so many columns is very inflexible and adding and removing values requires altering the structure of the table, rather than the data.

While compressing it into one field might seem to solve the problem, it actually makes the data contain the same structure in even more inflexible format, because you are removing the column:data semantics and solely relying on positional data. Making changes to this kind of data storage format will eventually be very time intensive and error prone to code.

It seems to me that you would do better if you inverted your problem and made a table that contains your booleans as rows, instead of having lots of columns. This is often the case. :)

Go with the table structure presented by JYelton instead, or something similar, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this, if you can, would be to create another table that would link to the existing one as a many-to-one and you could then use a select statement to find all records in the subtable matching the ID of your parent table. In this example, the new table would be named *info* (after the column) and the prior table is named *parent*:

```
SELECT parent.*
FROM info
INNER JOIN parent
ON parent.id = info.parent_id
WHERE info.data IN ( 2, 3 ) // see note 1
GROUP BY parent.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 // see note 2
```

**Note 1:** The positions within the string are now ints stored in the new table, in the column 'data'.

**Note 2:** You will need to specify the number of values specified above.

Thoughts: This query does not eliminate parent records where *additional* values match in the data table.